# Implement comparator for qsort. How to get rid of this warning?

Tags: c, function-pointers, qsort

I was wondering how to get rid of the following warning:

```
   kwic1.c:118:48: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int (const char *,
  const char *)' to parameter of type 'int (* _Nonnull)(const void *, const
  void *)' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

I am implementing a comparator for qsort. Here is my function

```
 int comparator(const char *p, const char *q)
 {
   int index_p = 0;
   int index_q = 0;

    while(p[index_p] != '\0')
    {
      if(isupper(p[index_p]))
         break;
     index_p++;
    }
   ...
```

I have tried casting `p` and `q`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Does this work though? Either you're sorting arrays of characters instead of pointers to arrays - this is very inefficient - or your `p` and `q` should be `const char **`.

Comment: If you're sorting characters in a string (so `"abracadabra"` will become `"aaaaabbcdrr"`), you wouldn't be stepping through the strings (you'd simply compare the two characters the arguments point at).  If you're sorting strings, you're passed two `const char **` values, not `const char *` values.  Either way, there are more problems than just the types of the arguments to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use (implicit) pointer type casting in your function:

```
int comparator(const void *p1, const void *q1){
    const char *p = p1, *q = q1;
    // The rest of the code requires no change
```

It's important for function prototypes to match exactly when passing as function pointers. i.e., you can't pass a `int (*)(const char*, const char*)` function pointer to a parameter of `int (*)(const void*, const void*)`. All you should do is convert the pointer into desired types in your comparison function.

Comment: @YipingWang I changed the name of the parameters from `p, q` to `p1, q1`.

Comment: You could just drop the casts. In C it is not necessary to cast from/to `void`-pointers.

Comment: `const char *p = p1, *q = q1;` will perfectly do.

Comment: @alk Yep. I forgot that. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Qsort is a truly generic function in C, but it trips people up because ***types matter***.

The arguments to the comparitor should be `(const void*)`.

If you were sorting `int`, then you could simply cast to `(const int*)`.

<sub>(The `void` was replaced by `int`.)</sub>

But it looks like you are sorting `(char*)`s. Thus you need to remember to properly cast that extra indirection: `(const void*)` → `(const (char*)*)` → `(const char**)`.

<sub>(The `void` was replaced by `char*`.)</sub>

I’m not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the comparitor snippet you have provided, but 
[Here is an example of qsort()ing c-strings.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47959703/2706707)

Comment: I'm pretty sure by `while(p[index_p] != '\0')` the sorted daya is of type `char`.

Comment: @iBug You are mixing types. For your code example, `p` is `char*`, which makes `p1` an alias for `const char**`.